# Discord Bot delete DM or restart the code

Tags: python

I have a bot that will challenge people with words, it works like this:

The bot send a message at a specific time to the channel and ask the users to send a pass over his Direct Message, then he check if the message are ok and if is he save the user and pay them. After three users he close the event and say that is closed.

My problem is that when my bot receive the first wrong message, he will not do anything, anymore.

How to delete the cache of the messages from the users to the bot?

Look my code:

```
from logging import error, shutdown
from discord.ext.commands import Cog
from discord.ext.commands import command
import discord

from ..db import db
import os
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

ADM_ROLE = os.getenv('ADMIN_ROLE_ID')
COINKIT_ID = os.getenv('COINKIT_ID')
MAIN = os.getenv('MAIN_CHAT')

adminRoleQuote = '<@&'+ ADM_ROLE + '>'
adminRole = int(ADM_ROLE)
coinKitBotId = int(COINKIT_ID)
mainChatChannel = int(MAIN)
   
#Check if a message is active
async def getActiveWord():
    try:
        active = db.record(f'SELECT * FROM wordschallenge WHERE active = 1 AND done = 0')
        if active == None or active == []:
            msgError = 'No words to challenge'
            return msgError 
        else:
            return active[1]
    except Exception as e: print(e)

#Get a answer from the database
async def getFreshAnswer():
    try:
        answer = db.record(f'SELECT * FROM wordschallenge WHERE active = 1 AND done = 0')
        if answer == None or answer == []:
            msgError = 'No words to challenge'
            return msgError #maybe change this to just a return because we do not need to send a message if don't have one
        else:
            return answer[3]
    except:
        print("No words founded for now.")
        #return None

#Get the winner one
async def getWinnerOne():
    try:
        getUserOne = db.record(f'SELECT winner1 FROM wordschallenge WHERE active = 1')
        return getUserOne
    except Exception as e: print(e)
    
#Get the winner two
async def getWinnerTwo():
    try:
        getUserTwo = db.record(f'SELECT winner2 FROM wordschallenge WHERE active = 1')
        return getUserTwo
    except Exception as e: print(e)
    

#Get the winner three
async def getWinnerThree():
    try:
        getUserThree = db.record(f'SELECT winner3 FROM wordschallenge WHERE active = 1')
        return getUserThree
    except Exception as e: print(e)
   

#Update the winner user one
async def setWinnerOne(userId):
    try:
        updateWord = db.execute(f'UPDATE wordschallenge SET winner1 = {str(userId)} WHERE active = 1  AND winner1 = "winner1"')
        return updateWord
    except Exception as e: print(e)
    

#Update the winner user two    
async def setWinnerTwo(userId):
    try:        
        updateWord = db.execute(f'UPDATE wordschallenge SET winner2 = {str(userId)} WHERE active = 1  AND winner2 = "winner2"')
        return updateWord        
    except Exception as e: print(e)
    
    
#Update the winner three
async def setWinnerThree(userId):
    try:        
        updateWord = db.execute(f'UPDATE wordschallenge SET winner3 = {str(userId)} WHERE active = 1 AND winner3 = "winner3"')
        return updateWord        
    except Exception as e: print(e)
    
    
#Disable the words challenge
async def disableChallenge():
    try:
        disableQuestion = db.execute(f'UPDATE wordschallenge SET active = 0, done = 1 WHERE active = 1')
        return disableQuestion
    except Exception as e: print(e)
    
#getWinnerOneFinal
async def getWinnerOneFinal():
    try:
        
        pass
    except Exception as e: print(e)

class Words(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @command(name='setword')
    async def settime(self, ctx, active, question, answer, winner1, winner2, winner3, done):
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            #Insert a new quiz into the database
            db.execute("INSERT INTO wordschallenge (active, question, answer, winner1, winner2, winner3, done) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (active), (question), (answer), (winner1), (winner2), (winner3), (done))
            db.commit()
            await ctx.send("Questions updated, check the active questions with the 'getword' command!")
           
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"You are not authorized to use this command, only {adminRoleQuote} can do that.")


    @command(name='getword')
    async def gettime(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            #get time from db
                       
            totalWords = db.record("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wordschallenge;")

            await ctx.send(f"The total active questions to make is: {totalWords[0]}")
           
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"You are not authorized to use this command, only {adminRoleQuote} can do that.")
            
           
            
            
    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        if not self.bot.ready:
            self.bot.cogs_ready.ready_up('words')
    
    @Cog.listener("on_message")
    async def greet(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot:
            #await message.channel.send(f"Hello {message.author.mention}")
            getTheWord = await getActiveWord()
            getAnswer = await getFreshAnswer()
            getWinOne = await getWinnerOne()
            getWinTwo = await getWinnerTwo()
            getWinThree = await getWinnerThree()
            ab = await disableChallenge()
            
            if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
                #all new messages process here
                                
                try:
                                
                    if getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() != getAnswer.lower():
                        await message.author.send(f"Wrong answer, please try again.")
                        
                        
                        


                    if getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] == 'winner1':
                        await message.author.send(f"Check in main chat if you was a winner {message.author.mention}")
                        await setWinnerOne(str(message.author.id))
                        db.commit()                   

                    if getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] != 'winner1' and str(message.author.id) == getWinOne[0]:
                        await message.author.send(f"{message.author.mention} You already won this challenge, wait for the next one.")


                    if getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] != 'winner1' and getWinTwo[0] == 'winner2':
                        await message.author.send(f"Check in main chat if you was a winner {message.author.mention}")
                        await setWinnerTwo(str(message.author.id))
                        db.commit()

                    if getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] != 'winner1' and getWinTwo[0] != 'winner2' and str(message.author.id) == getWinOne[0]:
                        await message.author.send(f"{message.author.mention} You already won this challenge, wait for the next one.")


                    if getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] != 'winner1' and getWinTwo[0] != 'winner2' and str(message.author.id) == getWinTwo[0]:
                        await message.author.send(f"{message.author.mention} You already won this challenge, wait for the next one.")


                    if getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] != 'winner1' and getWinTwo[0] != 'winner2' and getWinThree[0] == 'winner3':
                        await message.author.send(f"Check in main chat if you was a winner {message.author.mention}")
                        await setWinnerTwo(str(message.author.id))
                        db.commit()

                    if getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] != 'winner1' and getWinTwo[0] != 'winner2' and getWinThree[0] != 'winner3':
                        await message.author.send(f"{message.author.mention} All winners have been selected, wait for the next one.")
                        ab
                        db.commit()

                    else:
                       pass
                        
                        
                except Exception as e: print(e)
                    
                
  
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Words(bot))
    print('words.py has been loaded')
```

Here in the code if the bot send the message that the reply is wrong he will not work anymore checking the messages:

```
if getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() != getAnswer.lower():
                        await message.author.send(f"Wrong answer, please try again.")
```

So, how to deal with this?

Comment: I tried several ways of deal with it, but I can't reset or back to the start. He keeps getting the first message cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the future, it was an error with my logic.

```
elif
```

solved the problem (including not await on database stuff), so, here how the code is now:

```
from logging import disable, error, shutdown
from discord.ext.commands import Cog
from discord.ext.commands import command
import discord
import time
import asyncio

from discord.ext.commands.converter import PartialMessageConverter

from ..db import db
import os
import sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

ADM_ROLE = os.getenv('ADMIN_ROLE_ID')
COINKIT_ID = os.getenv('COINKIT_ID')
MAIN = os.getenv('MAIN_CHAT')

adminRoleQuote = '<@&'+ ADM_ROLE + '>'
adminRole = int(ADM_ROLE)
coinKitBotId = int(COINKIT_ID)
mainChatChannel = int(MAIN)
   
#Check if a message is active
async def getActiveWord():
    try:
        active = db.record(f'SELECT * FROM wordschallenge WHERE active = 1 AND done = 0')
        if active == None or active == []:
            msgError = 'No words to challenge'
            return msgError 
        else:
            return active[1]
    except Exception as e: print(e)

#Get a answer from the database
async def getFreshAnswer():
    try:
        answer = db.record(f'SELECT * FROM wordschallenge WHERE active = 1 AND done = 0')
        if answer == None or answer == []:
            msgError = 'No words to challenge'
            return msgError #maybe change this to just a return because we do not need to send a message if don't have one
        else:
            return answer[3]
    except:
        print("No words founded for now.")
        #return None

#Get the winner one
async def getWinnerOne():
    try:
        getUserOne = db.record(f'SELECT winner1 FROM wordschallenge WHERE active = 1')
        return getUserOne
    except Exception as e: print(e)
    
#Get the winner two
async def getWinnerTwo():
    try:
        getUserTwo = db.record(f'SELECT winner2 FROM wordschallenge WHERE active = 1')
        return getUserTwo
    except Exception as e: print(e)
    

#Get the winner three
async def getWinnerThree():
    try:
        getUserThree = db.record(f'SELECT winner3 FROM wordschallenge WHERE active = 1')
        return getUserThree
    except Exception as e: print(e)
   

#Update the winner user one
async def setWinnerOne(userId):
    try:
        updateWord = db.execute(f'UPDATE wordschallenge SET winner1 = {str(userId)} WHERE active = 1  AND winner1 = "winner1"')
        return updateWord
    except Exception as e: print(e)
    

#Update the winner user two    
async def setWinnerTwo(userId):
    try:        
        updateWord = db.execute(f'UPDATE wordschallenge SET winner2 = {str(userId)} WHERE active = 1  AND winner2 = "winner2"')
        return updateWord        
    except Exception as e: print(e)
    
    
#Update the winner three
async def setWinnerThree(userId):
    try:        
        updateWord = db.execute(f'UPDATE wordschallenge SET winner3 = {str(userId)} WHERE active = 1 AND winner3 = "winner3"')
        return updateWord        
    except Exception as e: print(e)
    
    
#Disable the words challenge
def pendingToPay():
    try:
        pendingTx = db.execute('UPDATE wordschallenge SET active = 2 WHERE active = 1')
        return pendingTx
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    
#getWinnerOneFinal
async def getWinnerOneFinal():
    try:
        
        pass
    except Exception as e: print(e)

class Words(Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @command(name='setword')
    async def settime(self, ctx, active, question, answer, winner1, winner2, winner3, done):
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            #Insert a new quiz into the database
            db.execute("INSERT INTO wordschallenge (active, question, answer, winner1, winner2, winner3, done) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (active), (question), (answer), (winner1), (winner2), (winner3), (done))
            db.commit()
            await ctx.send("Questions updated, check the active questions with the 'getword' command!")
           
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"You are not authorized to use this command, only {adminRoleQuote} can do that.")


    @command(name='getword')
    async def gettime(self, ctx):
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
            #get time from db
                       
            totalWords = db.record("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM wordschallenge;")

            await ctx.send(f"The total active questions to make is: {totalWords[0]}")
           
        else:
            await ctx.send(f"You are not authorized to use this command, only {adminRoleQuote} can do that.")
            
           
            
            
    @Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        if not self.bot.ready:
            self.bot.cogs_ready.ready_up('words')
    
    @Cog.listener("on_message")
    async def greet(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot:
            #await message.channel.send(f"Hello {message.author.mention}")
            getTheWord = await getActiveWord()
            getAnswer = await getFreshAnswer()
            getWinOne = await getWinnerOne()
            getWinTwo = await getWinnerTwo()
            getWinThree = await getWinnerThree()


            
            if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):
                                                               
                try:

                    if getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() != getAnswer.lower():
                        await message.author.send(f"Wrong answer, please try again.")
                        
                    elif getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] == 'winner1':
                        await message.author.send(f"Check in main chat if you was a winner {message.author.mention}")
                        await setWinnerOne(str(message.author.id))
                        db.commit()                   
                    
                    elif getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] != 'winner1' and str(message.author.id) == getWinOne[0]:
                        await message.author.send(f"{message.author.mention} You already won this challenge, wait for the next one.")
                    
                    elif getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] != 'winner1' and getWinTwo[0] == 'winner2':
                        await message.author.send(f"Check in main chat if you was a winner {message.author.mention}")
                        await setWinnerTwo(str(message.author.id))
                        db.commit()
                    
                    elif getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] != 'winner1' and getWinTwo[0] != 'winner2' and str(message.author.id) == getWinOne[0]:
                        await message.author.send(f"{message.author.mention} You already won this challenge, wait for the next one.")
                    
                    elif getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] != 'winner1' and getWinTwo[0] != 'winner2' and str(message.author.id) == getWinTwo[0]:
                        await message.author.send(f"{message.author.mention} You already won this challenge, wait for the next one.")
                    
                    elif getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] != 'winner1' and getWinTwo[0] != 'winner2' and getWinThree[0] == 'winner3':
                        await message.author.send(f"Check in main chat if you was a winner {message.author.mention}")
                        await setWinnerThree(str(message.author.id))
                        db.commit()
                        pendingToPay()
                        db.commit()
                        await message.author.send(f"{message.author.mention} All winners have been selected.")
                    
                    elif getTheWord == 1 and message.content.lower() == getAnswer.lower() and getWinOne[0] != 'winner1' and getWinTwo[0] != 'winner2' and getWinThree[0] != 'winner3':
                        await message.author.send(f"{message.author.mention} All winners have been selected, wait for the next one.")
                        
                                  
                        
                        
                    else:
                        pass
                      
                except:
                    pass
                finally:
                    pass
               
def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Words(bot))
    print('words.py has been loaded')
```

Maybe this can help someone on future.